# Android Mediaplayer rewinding on setDisplay

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, surfaceview

Whenever I call `setDisplay()` on a MediaPlayer while it is playing (i.e. `setDisplay(null)` when backgrounding a video to play audio in the background) the media player stutters and rewinds for some small amount of time. Once I comment out these lines, essentially restricting the application to only play audio, these stutters and consequent rewinds no longer occur. Any ideas what the issue may be?

EDIT:
So I think the cause of the problem might be android media player choosing the closest keyframe to resume from on each display change because it can''t render inbetween keyframes. Any ideas?

Comment: What device are you using?  It might be a characteristic of that device and not present on all Android devices.

Comment: I would guess it's responding to a change in video destination by backing up to the nearest key frame. Not sure why it would do that.

Comment: Im using a nexus 6p. Though I've tested on several other devices and it has the same behaviour.

Comment: I think that it might be media player choosing the closest keyframe to resume the video from on each display change like @fadden suggested.